# JQGRID persists in posting the original postData value when using reloadGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

My initial grid is build

```
    $("#dims_list").jqGrid({        
    url: "ajax_get_dims_for_grid.php",
    postData: {'dims_guid': $('#dims_guid').val()},
```

When I refresh the grid with a new parameter the original value is sent (persists)

```
      var dims_guid = $("#dims_guid").val(); // New value for the grid 
      $("#dims_list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{"dims_guid":dims_guid}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

I have monitored this in the Chrome developer window and can see the new value in var dims_guid but the old value is posted to the page that retrieves the data from the database.

I have just moved from freeJQgrid to Guriddo jqGrid

I actually tried the following code

```
     var url="ajax_get_dims_for_grid.php?dims_guid="+$("#dims_guid").val();
     $("#dims_list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{"url":url}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

And in Chrome the query string was duplicated with the old one taking precedence

**Query String Parameters**

dims_guid: 100d7c6d-bcba-4b13-8832-f9de7794498c

dims_guid: dbc02dbe-e3d8-4b7d-8389-2678221ea189

_search: false

nd: 1586531572226

rows: 20

page: 1

sidx:

sord: asc

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

If a postData is used to send parameters to the server this parameter (postData) extend every time the parameters that are posted to the server if a request is made. As per [documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#options). This array is appended directly to the url.

The problem you have is that you do not have correctly set the new parameter when you trigger the grid. What you do is:

```
var dims_guid = $("#dims_guid").val(); // New value for the grid 
    $("#dims_list").jqGrid('setGridParam' {"dims_guid":dims_guid}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

This way you append new parameter th the grid and do not have change the existing one. In order to make it correct it is needed to change this in postData like this

```
var dims_guid = $("#dims_guid").val(); // New value for the grid 
  $("#dims_list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{ "postData" : { "dims_guid":dims_guid} }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

I hope you understand the difference.

Another possible solution is to not use postData (remove postData from options) , but use url only to change the parameter, like you do in your second published code. Like this:

```
$("#dims_list").jqGrid({        
url: "ajax_get_dims_for_grid.php?dims_guid="+$("#dims_guid").val(),
```

and then

```
 var url="ajax_get_dims_for_grid.php?dims_guid="+$("#dims_guid").val();
 $("#dims_list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{"url":url}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Comment: Tony, thank you for the answer, all working now.  JQGrid is so comprehensive that I am still learning!